# How can I introspect a freemarker template to find out what variables it uses?

Tags: java, freemarker

I'm not at all sure that this is even a solvable problem, but supposing that I have a freemarker template, I'd like to be able to ask the template what variables it uses.

For my purposes, we can assume that the freemarker template is very simple - just "root level" entries (the model for such a template could be a simple Map).  In other words, I don't need to handle templates that call for nested structures, etc.

Comment: Do you want to print what model values are available when the template is processed? Or do you need to which variables are actually used in the template? Say `${foo.bar}`, you want to know that `foo` will be used? Do you need know before the template is processed or can it be after?

Comment: If ${foo} and ${bar} are in the template, I'd like to know that "foo" and "bar" are used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same task to get the list of variables from template on java side and don't found any good approaches to that except using reflection. I'm not sure whether there is a better way to get this data or not but here's my approach:

```
public Set<String> referenceSet(Template template) throws TemplateModelException {
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
    TemplateElement rootTreeNode = template.getRootTreeNode();
    for (int i = 0; i < rootTreeNode.getChildCount(); i++) {
        TemplateModel templateModel = rootTreeNode.getChildNodes().get(i);
        if (!(templateModel instanceof StringModel)) {
            continue;
        }
        Object wrappedObject = ((StringModel) templateModel).getWrappedObject();
        if (!"DollarVariable".equals(wrappedObject.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
            continue;
        }

        try {
            Object expression = getInternalState(wrappedObject, "expression");
            switch (expression.getClass().getSimpleName()) {
                case "Identifier":
                    result.add(getInternalState(expression, "name").toString());
                    break;
                case "DefaultToExpression":
                    result.add(getInternalState(expression, "lho").toString());
                    break;
                case "BuiltinVariable":
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unable to introspect variable");
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new TemplateModelException("Unable to reflect template model");
        }
    }
    return result;
}

private Object getInternalState(Object o, String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    Field field = o.getClass().getDeclaredField(fieldName);
    boolean wasAccessible = field.isAccessible();
    try {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        return field.get(o);
    } finally {
        field.setAccessible(wasAccessible);
    }
}
```

Sample project that I made for demonstrating template introspection can be found on github: https://github.com/SimY4/TemplatesPOC.git

Comment: This uses methods marked deprecated because they are to be for internal use going forward and could be completely replaced.  The code also didn't work for me as of late 2016 with FreeMarker 2.3.25.

Comment: @MichaelOryl Hi. I'm aware that my approach using the deprecated APIs and I personally wouldn't recommend using it. But its still works for me, even in 2016 and freemarker 2.3.25. You can view the working code at https://github.com/SimY4/TemplatesPOC.git

Answer (score 7):

one other way to get the variables from java. This just tries to process the template and catch the `InvalidReferenceException` to find all the variables in a freemarker-template

```
 /**
 * Find all the variables used in the Freemarker Template
 * @param templateName
 * @return
 */
public Set<String> getTemplateVariables(String templateName) {
    Template template = getTemplate(templateName);
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    Map<String, Object> dataModel = new HashMap<>();
    boolean exceptionCaught;

    do {
        exceptionCaught = false;
        try {
            template.process(dataModel, stringWriter);
        } catch (InvalidReferenceException e) {
            exceptionCaught = true;
            dataModel.put(e.getBlamedExpressionString(), "");
        } catch (IOException | TemplateException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to Load Template: " + templateName, e);
        }
    } while (exceptionCaught);

    return dataModel.keySet();
}

private Template getTemplate(String templateName) {
    try {
        return configuration.getTemplate(templateName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to Load Template: " + templateName, e);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only method I've seen that A) works and B) doesn't use deprecated FreeMarker methods.  Bravo.

Comment: @MichaelOryl what about using it for enormously huge template? Are you ready to render this template as many times as different variables in it?

Comment: This is working only for String parameters. If we have boolean or numeric it won't be caught with InvalidReferenceException. There are NonBooleanException, NonNumericException and you need to put bool/number in dataModel. But even this is not enough since sometimes if you have variable in if statement left and right values for example if somevariable == false then it throws _MiscTemplateException and it's really hard to parse that one :( 
This answer is ok for simple templates, but it cannot be used in general.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably late, but in case anyone else encountered this problem : you can use 'data_model' and 'globals' to inspect the model - data_model will only contain values provided by the model while globals will also contain any variables defined in the template. 
You need to prepend the special variables with a dot - so to access globals, use ${.globals}

For other special variables see http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/docs/ref_specvar.html

Comment: Actually, I'd like to get the list of variables in the template in my Java code.  I'd like to be able to do something like:

Template t;
....
List<Variable> = t.getReferenceVariables();

Comment: http://freemarker.org/docs/api/freemarker/template/Template.html#getRootTreeNode()

gives you a hashtable of the model

Comment: This does not answer the question. To list contents of the variables, you need to do more than this.

Comment: Unfortunately, while it works, `getRootTreeNode()` is deprecated. What is the replacement though?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for my very simple usecase (only using flat datastructure, no nesting (for example: ${parent.child}), lists or more specific) with dummy data provider:

```
public class DummyDataProvider<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1;

    public final Set<String> variables = new HashSet<>();

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public V get(Object key) {
        variables.add(key.toString());
        return (V) key;
    }
}
```

You can give this for processing to a template and when it finishes Set `variables` contains your variables.

This is very simplistic approach, which certainly needs improvement, but you get the idea.

Comment: Actually I was forced to use regex based solution, because <#if ..> and <#elseif ..> were invisible for this kind of DummyDataProvider. Not very clean solution. I would even use different template engine if there would be anything to consider. HTTL has asking for template variables as a first class citizen, but HTTL itself is dead and their documentation isn't the best of breed out there...

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Set<String> getNecessaryTemplateVariables(String templateName) throws TemplateModelException {
        Set<String> result = new HashSet<>();
        TemplateElement rootTreeNode = getTemplate(templateName).getRootTreeNode();
        if ("IteratorBlock".equals(rootTreeNode.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
            introspectFromIteratorBlock(result, rootTreeNode);
            return result;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rootTreeNode.getChildCount(); i++) {
            TemplateModel templateModel = rootTreeNode.getChildNodes().get(i);
            if (!(templateModel instanceof StringModel)) {
                continue;
            }
            Object wrappedObject = ((StringModel) templateModel).getWrappedObject();
            if ("DollarVariable".equals(wrappedObject.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
                introspectFromDollarVariable(result, wrappedObject);
            } else if ("ConditionalBlock".equals(wrappedObject.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
                introspectFromConditionalBlock(result, wrappedObject);
            } else if ("IfBlock".equals(wrappedObject.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
                introspectFromIfBlock(result, wrappedObject);
            } else if ("IteratorBlock".equals(wrappedObject.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
                introspectFromIteratorBlock(result, wrappedObject);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void introspectFromIteratorBlock(Set<String> result, Object wrappedObject) {
        try {
            Object expression = getInternalState(wrappedObject, "listExp");
            result.add(getInternalState(expression, "name").toString());
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException ignored) {
        }
    }

    private static void introspectFromConditionalBlock(Set<String> result, Object wrappedObject)
        throws TemplateModelException {
        try {
            Object expression = getInternalState(wrappedObject, "condition");
            if (expression == null) {
                return;
            }
            result.addAll(dealCommonExpression(expression));
            String nested = getInternalState(wrappedObject, "nestedBlock").toString();
            result.addAll(getNecessaryTemplateVariables(nested));
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException ignored) {
        }
    }

    private static Set<String> dealCommonExpression(Object expression)
        throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Set<String> ret = Sets.newHashSet();
        switch (expression.getClass().getSimpleName()) {
            case "ComparisonExpression":
                String reference = dealComparisonExpression(expression);
                ret.add(reference);
                break;
            case "ExistsExpression":
                reference = dealExistsExpression(expression);
                ret.add(reference);
                break;
            case "AndExpression":
                ret.addAll(dealAndExpression(expression));
            default:
                break;
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private static String dealComparisonExpression(Object expression)
        throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Object left = getInternalState(expression, "left");
        Object right = getInternalState(expression, "right");
        String reference;
        if ("Identifier".equals(left.getClass().getSimpleName())) {
            reference = getInternalState(left, "name").toString();
        } else {
            reference = getInternalState(right, "name").toString();
        }
        return reference;
    }

    private static String dealExistsExpression(Object expression) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Object exp = getInternalState(expression, "exp");
        return getInternalState(exp, "name").toString();
    }

    private static Set<String> dealAndExpression(Object expression)  throws NoSuchFieldException,
        IllegalAccessException{
        Set<String> ret = Sets.newHashSet();
        Object lho = getInternalState(expression, "lho");
        ret.addAll(dealCommonExpression(lho));
        Object rho = getInternalState(expression, "rho");
        ret.addAll(dealCommonExpression(rho));
        return ret;
    }

    private static void introspectFromIfBlock(Set<String> result, Object wrappedObject)
        throws TemplateModelException {
        result.addAll(getNecessaryTemplateVariables(wrappedObject.toString()));
    }

    private static void introspectFromDollarVariable(Set<String> result, Object wrappedObject)
        throws TemplateModelException {
        try {
            Object expression = getInternalState(wrappedObject, "expression");
            switch (expression.getClass().getSimpleName()) {
                case "Identifier":
                    result.add(getInternalState(expression, "name").toString());
                    break;
                case "DefaultToExpression":
                    result.add(getInternalState(expression, "lho").toString());
                    break;
                case "BuiltinVariable":
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        } catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            throw new TemplateModelException("Unable to reflect template model");
        }
    }

    private static Object getInternalState(Object o, String fieldName) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
        Field [] fieldArray = o.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fieldArray) {
            if (!field.getName().equals(fieldName)) {
                continue;
            }
            boolean wasAccessible = field.isAccessible();
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                return field.get(o);
            } finally {
                field.setAccessible(wasAccessible);
            }
        }
        throw new NoSuchFieldException();
    }

    private static Template getTemplate(String templateName) {
        try {
            StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(templateName);
            return new Template(null, stringReader, null);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Failed to Load Template: " + templateName, e);
        }
    }
```

I optimized SimY4's answer, and supported <#list> and <#if> block. Code is not fully tested

Answer (score -1):

Execute following regex on the template:

```
(?<=\$\{)([^\}]+)(?=\})
```

- (?<=\$\{) Matches everything followed by ${
- ([^\}]+) Matches any string not containing }
- (?=\}) Matches everything before }

Comment: You can only use a simple regex for pulling out straightforward `${whatever}` variables.  This won't find things referenced in `<#if whatever>` or looping constructs.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and none of posted solution made sense to me. What I came with is plugging custom implementation of 
`TemplateExceptionHandler`. Example:

```
final private List<String> missingReferences = Lists.newArrayList();
final Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_23);
cfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(new TemplateExceptionHandler() {

    @Override
    public void handleTemplateException(TemplateException arg0, Environment arg1, Writer arg2) throws TemplateException {
        if (arg0 instanceof InvalidReferenceException) {
            missingReferences.add(arg0.getBlamedExpressionString());
            return;
        }
        throw arg0;
    }

}

Template template = loadTemplate(cfg, templateId, templateText);

StringWriter out = new StringWriter();

try {
    template.process(templateData, out);
} catch (TemplateException | IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("oops", e);
}

System.out.println("Missing references: " + missingReferences);
```

Read more here: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_errorhandling.html