# Can Freemarker have Template model keys defined during runtime?

Tags: spring-boot, freemarker

I have to compose an email using Freemarker Template, whose model key 
will be defined by user inputs. Basically user will configure the template and both the template and template model values will be a part 
of browser request to the spring boot microservice controller. The need 
is to parse the template and fetch the model keys and pair up with the 
respective values. Thereafter the model will be set for template 
process. Any idea how to set the model keys for freemarker template to 
process.
In an attempt to parse using pattern search for `${abc}`, I used this 
pattern to get one model key in the user configured template. I can just 
set the fetched key in the model and use in template process, as shown

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\$\\{.*?\\})", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.DOTALL);
Matcher m = p.matcher(data.getEmailStartTemplate());
if (m.find()) {
    String theGroup = m.group(1);
    salutationKey = theGroup.substring(theGroup.indexOf('{') + 1, theGroup.indexOf('}'));
    System.out.format("'%s'\n", salutationKey);
}
Map<String, Object> salutationModel = new HashMap<String, Object>();
salutationModel.put(salutationKey, model.get("salutationBody"));
text = FreeMarkerTemplateUtils.processTemplateIntoString(template, salutationModel);
```

But how many matching model keys will be fetched is not definite. It can 
be more than one also. In such cases how to feed into template to 
process. Does freemarker support dynamic model key creation?

Comment: The template I am using will look like <html> <head></head> <body> <p>Dear ${firstName}${lastName},</p><p>${mainBody}</b></p><p>Thanks</p><p>${signature}</p><p>${location}</p></body> </html>

Comment: You wrote that template model value is a part of the request, how it looks like? Doesn't it have all "model keys"? You can also take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919189/how-can-i-introspect-a-freemarker-template-to-find-out-what-variables-it-uses

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear in the question.The request will have a json property for the template whose value will be as given :                                               <html> <head></head> <body> <p>Dear ${firstName}${lastName},</p><p>${mainBody}</b></p><p>Thanks</p><p>${signature}</p><p>${location}</p></body> </html>

Comment: Why do you need to extract the model variable names from the template (but that's impossible in general anyway, given the dynamic nature of the template language). The template refers to model variables like `firstName`, `lastName`. So somebody (a human being) has to specify the values for those. When/how in the workflow is that supposed to happen? The standard approach is that first you know the model, and then you create a template to render it.

Comment: An user can create as many templates for email each specific to cater a category viz. mail template for finance department, mail template for hr department, etc.So finance department can have ${firstName} and ${lastName} defined by user, while hr department might have none pf the above.Because the template model key  changes from one template to other hence I can't hardcode the same in the code.Hence seeking to extract the model keys during runtime and then feed with the values and send to process with Template engine.Please let me know if it is possible using Freemarker

Comment: Any inputs on the above ?I am still unable to reach to a correct solution

Comment: Finally I used the java regex pattern to look up the template variables such as ${firstName} or  ${lastName} or ${salutationBody} and created the template model and thereafter passed to template to process.